# trying to create a list based on the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

so below is my script , I am trying to create a function that for numbers 1-7, if i=1, then a, if i=2, then b, if i>2, then b+a**2

```
def generate_numbers(a,b):
        f=[]
        for i in range(1,8):
            if i==1:
                f.append(a)
            elif i==2:
                f.append(b)
            else:
                f.append(f[i-2]+f[i-1]**2)
        return f
```

so above is my function, so what I expected is
for `generate_numbers(0,1)`
I can get a list `[0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 27, 734]`
which is `generate_numbers(0, 1) == [0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 27, 734]`

however, with my script, it keeps pop up an error of "list index out of range", can anyone help with it?

Comment: The error occurs when you try to access the f[i-1] when i is 3. At that moment, f contains only 2 elements.

Comment: Your problem description should be modified! Your current description implies that for all i>2, value is b+a**2 (but you mean the previous value in the list plus the square of the value two positions before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply start with the list initialized to `[a, b]`.

```
def generate_numbers(a, b, n=5):
    xs = [a, b]
    for _ in range(n):
        xs.append(xs[-2] + xs[-1]**2)
    return xs
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception will be 
IndexError
What caused it?

In your last if condition, the index of f is
i-1, suppose i is 3, therefore the index should be two and f[2] is not defined because you didn't define f[2]!

So in order to correct your code, this is my code

```
def generate_numbers(a,b):
        f=[]
        for i in range(1,8):
            if i==1:
                f.append(a)
            elif i==2:
                f.append(b)
            else:
                f.append(f[i-1]+f[i]**2)
        return f
```

Because Python use index zero as first element

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
def generate_numbers(a,b):
        f=[]
        for i in range(1,8):
            if i==1:
                f.append(a) # now f[0] = a
            elif i==2:
                f.append(b) # now f[1] = b
            else:
                # when i = 3, you are accessing f[2] and f[1], but you didn't populate f[2], because the indexing starts at 0, so your append function is not populating from 1st index. 
                f.append(f[i-1]+f[i]**2) . # crashed here. 
        return f
```

Corrected code:

```
def generate_numbers(a,b):
        f=[]
        for i in range(1, 8):
            if i==1:
                f.append(a)
            elif i==2:
                f.append(b)
            else:
                # one possiblity is to extract the last and second last element using reverse slicing. 
                f.append(f[-2]+f[-1]**2)
        return f
```

Another possibilty:

```
def generate_numbers(a,b):
        f=[]
        # put a dummy element at 0th index.
        f.append(0) . # now f[0] = 0
        for i in range(1,8):
            if i==1:
                f.append(a) # f[1] = a
            elif i==2:
                f.append(b) # f[2] = b
            else:
                f.append(f[i-1]+f[i]**2) # now you can access f[i-1] and f[i-2]
        return f[1:] # return the list by slicing the first element as it was dummy element
```